# excel 2013 and 2016 not opening html reports

Tags: c#, excel-2013, excel-2016

We have an application which on server side generates html table and allows the user to download report as xls files. The application returns data in html format but is saved as xls.

In last one week or so, the reports have stopped working. We get error message saying

> Excel cannot open the file Report1.xls because the file format or
>   file extension is not valid. Verfiy that the file has not been
>   corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the file.

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: have you thought about moving over to using SSRS..?

Comment: We have more than 700 reports, it will take significant amount of development time to do that.

Comment: then sounds like you need to debug the current issue if you are not willing to convert them over to SSRS based on what you have posted.. it could be a number of reasons since we don't know how your application currently generates HTML Tables you would be getting a lot of guess work from our end.. what have you done besides posing the issue here..? do you have access to the source code..? if so start looking at the code and debugging..

Comment: I found the answer on microsoft forum. Microsoft has released a security update for excel in July which is causing this issue.  More info is here - 
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-excel/excel-2010-stopped-opening-excel-files-generate/f69beac3-5bcd-4531-a220-a67b4d09324e?auth=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else having similar issue, we were able to get around this by doing the below workaround -

> You can make use of existing Trusted Locations capabilities in Excel
>   2010, 2013, and 2016 via **File -> options -> Trust Center -> Trust
>   Center Settings -> Trusted Locations.**
>
> 1. You can save the web html file to a trusted location on the local machine (Excel comes with a set of default trust locations). If you do
>      not see the local folder location you trust for these files, then
>      press “Add new location…” button and add it in the Trusted Location
>      dialog. If the HTML document is in a trusted location the KB fix is
>      not applied (e.g. the unsafe HTML file is not blocked).
> 2. This approach may unblock you, but it carries some risk as files of any file type in Trusted Locations are fully trusted. If an
>      attacker can drop files into the trusted location they can easily
>      exploit users who open such documents. Be especially cautious when
>      specifying a custom folder as a trusted location.

This solution was found here - https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d2d84793-9920-45e3-baef-5027a4ac1ae0/kb3170008-for-office-2016-breaks-functionality-ms16088

Comment: I wish this extended to 2003 users as well. At least this answer helps users from 2007 and up

Answer (score 0):

Excel 2007 works fine,
Excel 2010 will open it again after installing the latest Windows Update,
Excel 2013 still have Problems by now

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow Matthias but this answer doesn't really answer the question "Is there any workaround for this issue?".